# node library to construct demo pages to exhaustively test out API

Tags: node.js, api, api-doc

Given an API I can imagine a javascript library (serverside in Node) may exist that can construct demo-pages to test out these API-methods exhaustively.

Something like: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer

Anyone knows of a library like this?

Comment: yeah sort of thanks. I however don't want my api to live on apiary...

Comment: Just looked up another example of what I meant (developers.pipedrive.com/v1) and found the answer: "Powered by http://github.com/mashery/iodocs " :)

Comment: Have you looked at Swagger?

Comment: @wprl: Swagger and mashery/iodocs seem to be similar (and will both do the job at first glance). Any advantage to choose swagger over iodocs? Thanks

Comment: I've used Swagger on a couple projects (it's generated by my baucis library).  The results have been good.  But, on the surface, I don't see a huge difference vs. iodocs… I hadn't run across iodocs before.  I am curious as well.